# Problems extracting keyword from GA cookie

Tags: php, javascript

Im currently having some troubles extracting the keyword from the cookie i just want the keyword thats all heres my code:

```
function parse_ga_cookie($cookie) 
{ 

 $values = sscanf($cookie, '%d.%d.%d.%d.utmcsr=%[^|]|utmccn=%[^|]|utmcmd=%[^|]|utmctr=%[^|]'); 

    if (count($values) !== 8) { 
        // return false; trigger_error(...); ... or whatever you like 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cookie value '$cookie' does not conform to the __utmz pattern"); 

    } 
    $keys = array('domain', 'timestamp', 'visits', 'sources', 'campaign', 'source', 'medium', 'keyword'); 

    return array_combine($keys, $values); 

} 

print_r(parse_ga_cookie($_COOKIE['__utmz']));
```

this will give all the keys but if i only print the keyword it will just give me array() :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function parse_ga_cookie($cookie) 
{ 

 $values = sscanf($cookie, '%d.%d.%d.%d.utmcsr=%[^|]|utmccn=%[^|]|utmcmd=%[^|]|utmctr=%[^|]'); 

    if (count($values) !== 8) { 
        // return false; trigger_error(...); ... or whatever you like 
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Cookie value '$cookie' does not conform to the __utmz pattern"); 

    } 
    $keys = array('domain', 'timestamp', 'visits', 'sources', 'campaign', 'source', 'medium', 'keyword'); 

    return array_combine($keys, $values); 

} 

$keyword=parse_ga_cookie($_COOKIE['__utmz']);
$keyword=$keyword['keyword'];
```

Comment: tnx alot i was thinking on that but i wasnt sure! :)